# get_dummies vs categorical data in r for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data

I'm working on R with machine learning. I was wondering if to test a machine learning model like SVM,ANN.. where Day_of_week, hour, min will be introduced in the template creation. If there is any difference passing these variables to categorical or get_dummies?

I know the get_dummies function creates multiple columns and assigns 0 or 1 according to observation. Passing those attributes to categorical does not create columns but for each attribute it defines several factors.

```
#   Day_of_week hour min                Time Sms       Date    avgSms
# 1           1    0   0 2012-01-01 00:00:00  10 2012-01-01     12
# 2           1    0  30 2012-01-01 00:30:00  11 2012-01-01     20
# 3           1    1   0 2012-01-01 01:00:00  13 2012-01-01     19
# 4           1    1  30 2012-01-01 01:30:00  10 2012-01-01     11
# 5           1    2   0 2012-01-01 02:00:00   7 2012-01-01     12
# 6           1    2  30 2012-01-01 02:30:00   3 2012-01-01      7
# 7           1    3   0 2012-01-01 03:00:00   3 2012-01-01     NA
# 8           1    3  30 2012-01-01 03:30:00   2 2012-01-01     NA
...          ...  ...  .....................   .. .........   .....
```

Function of the model:

```
fmla<-sms ~ Day_of_week + hour + min + avgsms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some functions in R automatically take factor variables and run what you would get from a dummy coded variable, lm() for instance does this. I'm not sure that is true for all functions though. I think there are three possibilities for the purpose of get_dummies.

1) it may be a redundancy from people more familiar with programs like SPSS that can't handle factor variables in the same way and thus require dummy coding.
2) it may be there in case you do not want to include all levels of your factor in your model. 
3) some analyses get goofed up with a factor variable so having all of your IVs as numeric might be ideal. For instance if you wanted (or any function you use wanted) to calculate the covariance matrix, factor variables would result in an error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: My Day_of_week, hour, min is an integer and I can enter as categorical that puts each attribute as categorical and indicates me how many factors it has. I'm going to apply Random forest to a machine learning technique and my question was whether it would have any effect passing those attributes that are integers to categorical.

Comment: I think I'm confused a little on the terminology. When you say categorical are you talking about factor? R has a factor data type which is composed of multiple levels. Why not keep the data as numeric rather than changing it into a factor?

Comment: They should be treated the same as long as whatever you are using to do the RandomForest can handle both data types